# List/Dict comprehension in Python to update a dictionary with keys and values from a string

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

Does anyone know how to convert below for loop into a list or dictionary comprehension in one line? type(letter) = string,type(stringOne) = string,type(dictResult) = dictionary.For example, stringOne = 'abcddd', I want the output to be dictResult = {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 3} Thanks!!!

```
stringOne = 'abcddd'
dictResult = {}
for letter in stringOne:
    dictResult[letter] = dictResult.get(letter,0) + 1
```

Comment: Your `for` shouldn't work. It should raise an Index error.

Comment: Use `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find unique keys with set and then count. Note the `set` doesn't not keep (keys) insertion order!

```
stringOne = 'abcddd'

dictResult = {char: stringOne.count(char) for char in set(stringOne)}

print(dictResult)
```

Comment: You *100%* should never replace the above for-loop with this dict comprehension, though. Generically speaking. Although in this case it isn't a big deal, but you are trading a linear time algorithm with a quadratic time algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Make use of Counter will do. Save you the time to do a loop for the string. Can just convert to dictionary later if you required it to be in dictionary type.

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(stringOne)
dict(counter)
```